# Не вызывается метод Seed во время запуска приложения Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Было всё замечательно, всё мне нравилось, но как только добавил OnModelCreating, всё пошло не так. Раньше каждый раз гарантированно приложение заходило в миграцию, затем в функцию Seed во время запуска, и в БД заносились данные, которые создавал в Seed. Но с расширением классов для БД, с появлением в контексте проклятого OnModelCreating, приложение не заходит ни в миграцию, ни в Seed. В чём может быть проблема..? Грешу на то, что к этому может быть причастна Identity, которая своей дичи ещё добавляет в БД

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}

public class Instructor : User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public Instructor()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }
}

public class Student : User
{
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    public Subject()
    {
        Instructors = new List<Instructor>();
    }
}

public class Evaluation
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Evaluation> Evaluations { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("StudentsWebsiteDb") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
            .HasMany(i => i.Instructors)
            .WithMany(s => s.Subjects)
            .Map(k => k.MapLeftKey("UserId")
            .MapRightKey("SubjectId")
            .ToTable("SubjectInstructor"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Evaluation>().HasKey(e => new { e.StudentId, e.SubjectId });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Метод Seed:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        ApplicationUserManager userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<User>(context));
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        Dictionary<User, string> students = new Dictionary<User, string>();
        Dictionary<User, string> instructors = new Dictionary<User, string>();
        List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>();

        IdentityRole deanRole = new IdentityRole { Name = "dean" };
        roleManager.Create(deanRole);

        IdentityRole instructorRole = new IdentityRole { Name = "instructor" };
        roleManager.Create(instructorRole);

        IdentityRole studentRole = new IdentityRole { Name = "student" };
        roleManager.Create(studentRole);

        User dean = new User { UserName = "yyyyyyy@mail.ru", Email = "yyyyyyyy@mail.ru", Name = "Ruslan", Surname = "Krivoshein", Nickname = "guitarhero" };
        IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(dean, "qweqwe123!");
        dean.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim { ClaimType = "Nickname", ClaimValue = dean.Nickname });
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            userManager.AddToRole(dean.Id, deanRole.Name);
        }

        instructors.Add(new Instructor { UserName = "norbertwiener@science.ru", Email = "norbertwiener@science.ru", Name = "Norbert", Surname = "Wiener", Nickname = "Mr.Wiener" }, "wiener");
        instructors.Add(new Instructor { UserName = "claudeshannon@science.ru", Email = "claudeshannon@science.ru", Name = "Claude", Surname = "Shannon", Nickname = "Mr.Shannon" }, "shannon");
        instructors.Add(new Instructor { UserName = "alanturing@science.ru", Email = "alanturing@science.ru", Name = "Alan", Surname = "Turing", Nickname = "Mr.Turing" }, "turing");
        instructors.Add(new Instructor { UserName = "johnneumann@science.ru", Email = "johnneumann@science.ru", Name = "John", Surname = "Neumann", Nickname = "Mr.Neumann" }, "neumann");
        instructors.Add(new Instructor { UserName = "andreykolmogorov@science.ru", Email = "andreykolmogorov@science.ru", Name = "Andrey", Surname = "Kolmogorov", Nickname = "Mr.Kolmogorov" }, "kolmogorov");
        instructors.Add(new Instructor { UserName = "alberteinstein@science.ru", Email = "alberteinstein@science.ru", Name = "Albert", Surname = "Einstein", Nickname = "Mr.Einstein" }, "einstein");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<User, string> instructor in instructors)
        {
            IdentityResult res = userManager.Create(instructor.Key, instructor.Value);
            instructor.Key.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim { ClaimType = "Nickname", ClaimValue = instructor.Key.Nickname });
            if (res.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(instructor.Key.Id, instructorRole.Name);
            }
        }

        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "kirkrotorkrik@mail.ru", Email = "kirkrotorkrik@mail.ru", Name = "Kirill", Surname = "Krotov", Nickname = "Mole" }, "1krotkrot!");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "nickkkyyeremin@mail.ru", Email = "nickkkyyeremin@mail.ru", Name = "Nikolay", Surname = "Yeremin", Nickname = "erema" }, "!qwE12");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "fe0fan0v@bk.ru", Email = "fe0fan0v@bk.ru", Name = "Sergey", Surname = "Feofanov", Nickname = "DarkSide13" }, "ezzzy_0");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "someoneb100@mail.ru", Email = "someoneb100@mail.ru", Name = "Andrey", Surname = "Petrov", Nickname = "SomeoneB" }, "ap1234!");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "fyrfyrfyr1324@gmail.com", Email = "fyrfyrfyr1324@gmail.com", Name = "Alexandra", Surname = "Yeremina", Nickname = "CrazyFox" }, "foxy_777");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "oskarsmile12@yandex.ru", Email = "oskarsmile12@yandex.ru", Name = "Oskar", Surname = "Steblev", Nickname = "The_Best" }, "x1x1x1!");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "eagleandrew@mail.ru", Email = "eagleandrew@mail.ru", Name = "Andrey", Surname = "Orlov", Nickname = "TheEagle" }, "ea6le/");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "katypitch@gmail.com", Email = "katypitch@gmail.com", Name = "Ekaterina", Surname = "Pitch", Nickname = "Pretty" }, "kexxx:*");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "crazy07taly@mail.ru", Email = "crazy07taly@mail.ru", Name = "Stanislav", Surname = "Taly", Nickname = "HawkTaly" }, "h2so4)");
        students.Add(new Student { UserName = "maximusalive666@mail.ru", Email = "maximusalive666@mail.ru", Name = "Maxim", Surname = "Zhitnev", Nickname = "Maximus" }, "max/max");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<User, string> student in students)
        {
            IdentityResult res = userManager.Create(student.Key, student.Value);
            student.Key.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim { ClaimType = "Nickname", ClaimValue = student.Key.Nickname });
            if (res.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(student.Key.Id, studentRole.Name);
            }
        }

        subjects.Add(new Subject { Id = 1, Name = "Physic" });
        subjects.Add(new Subject { Id = 2, Name = "Math" });
        subjects.Add(new Subject { Id = 3, Name = "Electrical and electronics" });
        subjects.Add(new Subject { Id = 4, Name = "Theory of automata" });
        subjects.Add(new Subject { Id = 5, Name = "Informatics" });
        foreach (Subject subject in subjects)
        {
            context.Subjects.Add(subject);
        }

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: как по мне то можно без OnModelCreating обойтись. И приведите код Seed(). Identity здесь не при чем, он в ентити просто создает несколько таблиц.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, привёл. Но я здесь добавил только создание предметов. И программа в этот метод вообще не заходит почему-то...

Comment: а ещё если и заходит в него, что таблица Subjects не заполняется

Comment: было было бы неплохо перед base.Seed(context); написать context.SaveChanges();

Comment: в Global.asax нужно прописать Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer()); в начале Application_Start(). Мне хватает так, хотя в ответе ниже тоже неплохо.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, не думаю, что дело в `context.SaveChanges();`, потому что без него хорошо заполняется, если правильно заполнять)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На зарубежном форуме нашёлся вот такой ответ:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
MyContext db = new MyContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Больше не буду бояться заходить на него)